# Different Date Conversions Compared to the Operating System Time Zone

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have a problem converting a date to a long format.

When the time zone is set to:

> (UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London

I have the following conversion: `new Date(1556143200000);`

> Wed Apr **24** 2019 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (UK Daylight Time)

When the time zone is set to:

> (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna

It is different: `new Date(1556143200000);`

> Thu Apr **25** 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

The date changes by one day. Could you help me understand?

Comment: 23:00:00 GMT+1 is next day 00:00:00 GMT+2 - try with 21:00:00 or noon

Comment: Feel free to delete this. Days in computer worlds start at 00:00:00